# Betaflight Camera Angle

Tags: betaflight

What does the camera angle setting in betaflight effect?  Does it affect roles in acro?  Does it affect angle mode?

I feel like it's just a setting that does not affect my life.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The features add the yaw during rolls. If the camera is pointing straight forward a roll of the quad also looks like a roll in the camera. As soon as the camera is pointing up the roll of the quad moves the camera in a circle and the roll does not look like a roll in the camera. You have to add YAW inputs to correct the image.

This feature adds the according yaw input. But this only works correctly if you fly at the given angle. If the quad is flying at a different angle the roll will not look perfect in the camera and you would have to apply yaw to correct this again. Sometimes it is used for whoops in level mode but I'd also say that this setting isn't well suited for freestyle.

The feature can be active in acro and angle mode (it does not work in head-free mode). To activate the feature you have set the camera angle and to go to the modes tab and activate the "FPV ANGLE MIX". You can activate it with a switch only on certain modes.

Answer (score 5):

The camera angle setting in Betaflight is not commonly used but can be used to remix the controls into the axis of the camera. So roll would roll about the center of the camera view and yaw will keep the horizon flat. Essentially it would allow you to control the drone as if it were perfectly level while you are flying at the angle of the camera. Most people don't bother using it because it can cause bad flying habits.